# Как поменять цвет посещенной ссылки , но не везде

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем привет , столкнулся с проблемой , возможно ли не поменять а убрать полностью цвет посещенной ссылки в css ?
Копаю гугл , везде написано поставить тотже цвет что и цвет текста , но такой вариант не подходит, так как на сайте есть разные блоки с разными цветами.
Спасибо

Comment: Что такое "убрать цвет"? Сделать цвет ссылки равным цвету фона?

Answer (score 5):

```
a, a:visited, a:hover, a:active {
  color: inherit;
}
```

Можно так.

Answer (score 1):

Вы сказали, что "на сайте есть разные блоки с разными цветами", т.е. эти блоки имеют свой класс, этим вы и можете воспользоваться.

Например у Вас используются блоки с классом **.a1** и **.a2**.
Если Вам надо поменять цвет посещённой ссылки в **.a1**, то сделайте так:

```
.a1 a:visited {color: #07f;}
```

А если нужно поменять цвет посещённой ссылки везде, кроме этих DIVов, то пишите так:

```
a:visited {color: #07f;}
.a1 a:visited, .a2 a:visited {color: #00f;}
```

Answer (score -1):

Решил , присвоил каждому блоку цвет посещенной ссылки что и цвет блока 
Например

```
.int a:visited {
color:blue;
}
```

Comment: А зачем минусовать? Если человек дал ответ на свой же вопрос?